# Problema al crear un PDF con JSPDF en formato CMYK y arbrirlo en ILLUSTRATOR se invierten los colores

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf, imagemagick, illustrator

Buen dia, compañeros programadores espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con este problema.

Estoy usando Angular en el frontend para crear un archivo pdf con la libreria JsPDF a partir de una imagen CMYK la cual es anteriormente tratada con ImageMagick, el PDF se genera bien el problema es cuando se abre el PDF en Illustrator se invierten los colores

Este es el código que estoy usando para generar el PDF del lado del FrontEnd.

```js
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = DataUrl;

    image.onload = () => {
      let pageWidth = image.naturalWidth;
      let pageHeight = image.naturalHeight;

      let pdf = null;

      if (pageWidth > pageHeight) {
        pdf = new jsPDF({
          orientation: 'landscape',
        });

        pdf.set
      } else {
        pdf = new jsPDF({
          orientation: 'portrait'
        });
      }
      pdf.addImage(image, 0, 0, pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth(), pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight());

      pdf.save(`${projectSelected.n_name}.pdf`);
    }
```

NOTAS:
La misma imagen que uso para generar el PDF la uso para crear un PDF desde una herramienta externa y todo sale bien cuando la abro en Illustrator.

Si alguien sabe la solución o puede brindarme alguna documentación le agradeceria ya que llevo días con este problema y no le encuentro solución.